# SQL query to find average points

Tags: sql, pandas

I have a database containing information on a game with columns as below:
[game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75FIb.png)

I am trying to create a query to return 2 columns **team** and **average_score** with the following conditions:
1. avg_score is the team's average number of score in "away" games(the team's name appears in away_team column)
2. only include teams that have played at least 30 away matches.
3. only return the top 10 teams in descending order by average away-goals.

I have tried the following query:

```
    SELECT away_team AS team, round(avg(away_score),3) AS ave_goals 
    FROM results
    WHERE date >= 2000-01-01 AND neutral = 'FALSE'
    group by away_team HAVING COUNT(away_team) >=30
    ORDER BY ave_goals DESC
    LIMIT 10
```

This query does not give the desired result. What am i doing wrong?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Your current query does not look far off to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps with quotes around the date it would work:

```
SELECT away_team AS team, round(avg(away_score),3) AS ave_goals 
FROM results
WHERE date >= '2000-01-01' AND neutral = 'FALSE'
GROUP BY away_team
HAVING COUNT(away_team) >=30
ORDER BY ave_goals DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems correct, but seems `date` condition is wrong and I think we need to add `upper()` function on your neutral column.

```
select * from 
    (select away_team as team
        , round(avg(away_score),3) as ave_goals
    from results
    where cast(date as date) >= '2000-01-01' and upper(neutral)='FALSE'
    group by away_team
    having count(away_team) >= 30) t1
order by t1.ave_goals desc
limit 10
```

Comment: @F.Ar, I also suggest to cast your date column as date `cast(date as date)`